# conversion of discrete to continuous

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics

Given $N_{j+1}-N_j=kN_j$

How can I substitute some time variable in to make $delta(t)$ small? Meaning change in time.

I need to show $N_j=e^{(j\ln(1+k))}$

How can I rewrite the given in terms of delta t in order to take limit to find derivative ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this dynamics is solvable, giving $N_j=(1+k)^jN_0$ for every integer $j$, hence $N_j=n(j)$ where $n(t)=(1+k)^tN_0$ for every real number $t$. This is $n(t)=\mathrm e^{at}N_0$ for $a=\ln(1+k)$ hence $n'(t)=a\mathrm e^{at}N_0$, that is, $n'(t)=\ln(1+k)\cdot n(t)$.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful but it is solving by analogy. I am asked to sub t=j*deltat and take limit to find derivative to solve by separation. I have hard time wrapping head around this.

Comment: Analogy? Not at all, as explained in the answer. // Note that the definition of $\delta(t)$ in your question is a complete mystery.

Comment: I meant lowercase delta t. As in change of time.

Comment: I will talk with professor tomorrow and clear up my mess here

Comment: How do you go from an equation true for all j in Z to an equivalent equation true for all real numbers?

Comment: You mean, how to go from $(1+k)^j$ to $(1+k)^t$? Hmmmm...

Comment: Yeah from integers to the real numbers.

Comment: Of course there are plenty of functions $n(\ )$ such that $n(j)=N_j$ for every integer $j$, but this one seems rather natural, no?